# Create Temporary Excel Chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

```
Sub aaGraphing()
'
' aaGraphing Macro
'

'
    Range("L948:W949,D948:D949").Select
    Range("D949").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "Analytics!$L$948:$W$949,Analytics!$D$948:$D$949")
End Sub
```

This code creates a chart of the data I want. Is there a way to way to make the created chart temporary so that when you click anywhere outside of the chart it deletes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular module....

```
Option Explicit


Public PlotName As String
Public PlotRange As Range


Sub Tester()
AddPlot ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B7,D3:D7")
End Sub

Sub AddPlot(rng As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
        PlotName = .Name
        .Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rng.Address())
    End With
    Set PlotRange = rng
    Application.EnableEvents=False    
    rng.Select
    Application.EnableEvents=True
End Sub

Sub RemovePlot(rng As Range)
    If Not PlotRange Is Nothing Then
        If Application.Intersect(rng, PlotRange) Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next
            rng.Parent.Shapes(PlotName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Sheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    RemovePlot Target
End Sub
```

Comment: I am really surprised. I seriously wasn't expecting the _SelectionChange event to work so well. I thought it was very unreliable. I was completely and absolutely wrong and thus I have to delete my answer. Thanks for the code.

Comment: PS: this is the second time when I say that something is impossible and you prove me wrong. I don't give too much importance to the first time because I didn't like the asker at all and didn't analyse the problem; but this time I was so sure... Live to learn; I guess that I should remove some of my prejudices with VBA.

Comment: Many things are possible, but not all are good ideas... Just depends on quite how robust you need it to be. for example my code will break if the user saves and closes the workbook immediately after creating the plot. A good addition would be to have `AddPlot` delete any already-existing chart.

Comment: One suggestion if someone else is using this is to create a range name to go to before initiating the Macro. Thus in Sub Tester() Start by selecting a range. In my case it was Range("TCKWH.V.1").Select This will stop any errors from accidentally adding extra data to the graph.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `SelectionChange` event of the worksheet to delete the chart. Below I am assuming there is only one shape - the chart - that might be on the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Me.Shapes.Count = 1 Then
        Me.Shapes(1).Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

It is possible (I believe) to dynamically attach this event, and remove it. However, I believe that it is a *little* complicated.

An alternative might be to use `Application.OnTime` to delete it after a period of time.

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:40"), "ProcedureToDelete"
```

will run the procedure named 'ProcedureToDelete' after 40 seconds. In this procedure you might want to make sure the the selection is in the worksheet, not in the chart that you are about to delete.

You could, in the timed-procedure, check to see if the chart is currently selected. If not, delete it, otherwise set the timer again.

Comment: Do you consider this a sensible/reliable solution?

Comment: @varocarbas Well, personally, I would rather add a button to the worksheet that the user can click on to delete the chart. Still, I would prefer my solution to attaching an external program.

Comment: don't misunderstand me! My solution was: there is no practical solution for what you want. The external program was like saying "it is so difficult that unless having an external program doing such a thing...". Anyway, it might not be too reliable, but this thing of using Application.OnTime is the closest option you have here and I didn't realise about it: good work.

Comment: @varocarbas I wouldn't say my solution is perfect but, with some more error-handling code (checking where the `Selection` is, etc.) it could be made reliable. How reliable could it be if you involve an external application :). As I say, I'd prefer not to use `SelectionChange` at all, and prefer a button. The `OnTime` is not such a concern because, if something goes wrong, we can just not re-initiate it, and it will quietly disappear.

Comment: You don't need to convince me; I am the one who up-voted your answer.

Comment: @varocarbas No worries. I was just outlining the implications for anyone else who might read this ;) (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Your right a button on the worksheet to toggle the deletion of the chart. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently we were wrong; mainly I was wrong. @Tim Williams has proven that it is possible to create a highly reliable approach to account for what was expected!!!

Comment: @varocarbas It is not that different to my suggestion ;). It's neater and includes the error-handling which I suggested, but omitted. It could even be improved using a Property of the worksheet, so that RemovePlot would not be called if the chart didn't exist. I sound like I'm being defensive - but I'm really not!! There is nothing wrong with using `SelectionChange`; we just need to make sure that it is error-proof and doesn't do too much.

Comment: ah come on! You are being extremely defensive! Accept defeat like a man :)

Comment: @varocarbas He, he. Okay. Defeated.

Comment: Defeated or not. Thank you very much! =)

Comment: @MichaelDowney (not really defeated, he, he). Glad you sorted.